# Why would `cksum` be running slower than `md5sum`?

Tags: backup, checksum

I've been backing up Windows installer images for my virtual machine, and to verify the data was transferred correctly, I've been using `cksum`. Out of curiosity, I decided to compare the times it took for `cksum` to run vs. `md5sum` for the same files. The results after running each operation several times (to make sure it wasn't related to I/O caching) was that `md5sum` consistently took about half the time as `cksum`. I have two questions...

1. Why would `md5sum` be so much faster than `cksum`?
2. For the purpose of finding random errors, is there any reason I should choose `cksum` over `md5sum`.

I am running Arch Linux.

**Note:** this is not a question about which is better. That has been covered many times before, and I know `md5sum` is not to be used as a *cryptographic* hash. I am asking specifically about the use of `md5sum` as a means of finding *random errors*.

Comment: Important to note here is that the speed diference is `coreutils`-specific, in ruby for example `crc32` (using zlib) is twice as fast as `md5` (using openssl). So the other way around than you observed with `cksum` and `md5sum`. Measured on `dd if=/dev/urandom of=test bs=4M count=20` file.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The calculations performed by both hashing algorithms are different, so it's not surprising that they have different performance characteristics. On Linux systems, both `md5sum` and `cksum` are typically the GNU `coreutils` versions. `md5sum` uses the C library's MD5 functions which are quite well optimised and operate on block contents 32 bits at a time (see [`md5.c`](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=crypt/md5.c;h=ecd52e4896cfd33e5ac360141ea69cc1097f8eb6;hb=HEAD) and [`md5-block.c`](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=crypt/md5-block.c;h=35e99addec6aeafcfcec0657d97c1cb754d95851;hb=HEAD)). `cksum` uses its own CRC implementation which operates on contents one byte at a time (see [`cksum.c`](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/coreutils.git/tree/src/cksum.c)). That could be a contributing factor to `md5sum`'s speed compared to `cksum`; there are no doubt others.

To decide which tool is more appropriate for finding random errors, you'd need to analyse the mathematical properties of the algorithms involved. At a very basic level, `cksum` produces a 32-bit hash whereas `md5sum` produces a 128-bit hash, so just from that the latter should be more resistant to accidental collisions (and thus be better at detecting random errors, especially as the number of flipped bits increases).

The only reason I can see to choose `cksum` over `md5sum` is that the former is specified by POSIX, so any POSIX system will have it — if that's a factor then `cksum` would be more appropriate.

(Regarding your comment about cryptographic hashes, `cksum` isn't a cryptographic hash at all so the question is moot.)